# Flotr & Server Side Processing

Tags: java, javascript, server-side, flotr

Is there any way to send object / image content type created by Flotr (http://code.google.com/p/flotr/) to server side scripting.

For comparison, with protovis () we can send SVG generated to server side servlet to have PNG / JPG result with Apache Batik.

Appreciate for any clue.

Regards,

Dino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Flotr generates a `<canvas>` HTML element image, which you can convert to base64 encoding with the `canvas.toDataURL()` method.

Then, it should not be painful to send it to web server with an AJAX HTTP POST call.

Cheers,